OpenAI API: How do I upload a file and ask a model about it?
I am trying to upload a PDF file and ask the model to give me a JSON object containing its data by what it understood.
Here is my code:
app.get("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!openai) {
    res.status(500).send("OpenAI object not created");
    return;
  }

  // Step 1: Upload the PDF file
  const response = await openai.files.create({
    purpose: "assistants",
    file: fs.createReadStream("./test.pdf"),
  });

  // Step 2: Ask OpenAI to convert the PDF to JSON and extract data
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: "gpt-4o",
    messages: [
      {
        role: "assistant",
        content: "get all the datafrom the pdf file I uploaded",
      },
    ],
    temperature: 0.7,
  });

  // Step 3: Handle the response and extract the data
  const data = completion; // Adjust this based on the actual response structure

  res.send(data);
});

Here is a response:
{
    "id": "chatcmpl-9sodJtcgf7l5sDTbzY0yHJ7o9jd6u",
    "object": "chat.completion",
    "created": 1722851373,
    "model": "gpt-4o-2024-05-13",
    "choices": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "I'm sorry, but I cannot access or retrieve data from the PDF file you mentioned. However, if you can provide the text or specific details from the document, I'd be happy to help you interpret or analyze the information. Please let me know how you would like to proceed!"
            },
            "logprobs": null,
            "finish_reason": "stop"
        }
    ],
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 19,
        "completion_tokens": 55,
        "total_tokens": 74
    },
    "system_fingerprint": "fp_4e2b2da518" }

Let me know how I can link the document to the question because I'm using Node.js with Typescript with the official OpenAI library and I'm struggling with that.

Problem
Use the OpenAI Assistants API. It's the most complex one, for sure. It's not that straightforward to use. The flow is fundamentally different from the Chat Completions API or the Completions API.
Solution
Before you start with the Assistants API flow, upload the file you want to use with an assistant.
Python
my_file = client.files.create(
    file=open("mydata.jsonl", "rb"),
    purpose="assistants"
)

Node.js
const myFile = await client.files.create({
    file: fs.createReadStream("mydata.jsonl"),
    purpose: "assistants",
});


After you upload the file, here are the steps you need to follow to get a response from the assistant:
Step 1: Create an assistant
Python
my_assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    name="Customer Support Chatbot",
    instructions="You are a customer support chatbot. When asked a question, answer from the uploaded file.",
    tools=[{"type": "file_search"}],
)

Node.js
const myAssistant = await client.beta.assistants.create({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    name: "Customer Support Chatbot",
    instructions: "You are a customer support chatbot. When asked a question, answer from the uploaded file.",
    tools: [{ type: "file_search" }],
});


Step 2: Create a thread
Python
my_thread = client.beta.threads.create()

Node.js
const myThread = await client.beta.threads.create();


Step 3: Add the user's message to the thread
Python
my_message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
  thread_id="thread_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  role="user",
  content="How can I enforce my guarantee?",
  attachments=[
    {
      file_id: "file-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      tools: [{ type: "file_search" }],
    }
  ],
)

Node.js
const myMessage = await client.beta.threads.messages.create(
    (thread_id = "thread_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    { 
      role: "user",
      content: "How can I enforce my guarantee?",
      attachments: [
        {
          file_id: "file-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          tools: [{ type: "file_search" }],
        }
      ],
    }
);


Step 4: Run the assistant using the polling helper provided by OpenAI (Python link, Node.js link)
Python
my_run = client.beta.threads.runs.create_and_poll(
    thread_id="thread_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    assistant_id="asst_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
)

Node.js
const myRun = await client.beta.threads.runs.createAndPoll(
    (thread_id = "thread_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    { assistant_id: "asst_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
);


Step 5: Retrieve the assistant's answer
Python
all_messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(
    thread_id="thread_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
)

Node.js
const allMessages = await client.beta.threads.messages.list(
    (thread_id = "thread_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
);


I don't have client.beta in openai library in node.js with typescript

@Noam Azoulay Simply switch the word client with the openai. It doesn't affect the functionality. It's just the variable you initialized the OpenAI package with.

@Noam Azoulay Also, feel free to subscribe to my YouTube channel, where I post 100% practical AI-related tutorials. A new OpenAI Assistants API tutorial is coming out today!

I know that my variables name is different but Im saying that typescript doesnt recognize .beta....

Then upgrade the OpenAI package: npm install openai@latest
